# Implicit polynomial curve fitting

Tags: curves, least-squares, data-analysis

Suppose I have a collection of $N$ points in the plane, $S=\{(x_i,y_i) \}_{i=1}^N$, and I want to describe the points as an approximate zero level-set of a polynomial of degree $d$, where $d$ is given. That is, I want to find a polynomial of the form
$$P_d(x,y) :=\sum_{n=0}^d \sum_{k=0}^n a_{k,n-k} x^k y^{n-k}$$
such that all points in $S$ satisfy $$P_d(x_i,y_i) \approx 0.$$
Is this "implicit curve fitting", well known? My intuition from standard curve fitting is to try minimizing
$$\sum_{i=1}^N P_d(x_i,y_i)^2 $$
with respect to all of the coefficients $\{a_{k,l}\}$. If there's a better way of doing this I'd like to know it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Taubin's papers](http://mesh.brown.edu/taubin/publications.html), especially:

[Estimation Of Planar Curves, Surfaces And Nonplanar Space Curves Defined By Implicit Equations, With Applications To Edge And Range Image Segmentation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.474.7664&rep=rep1&type=pdf), by G. Taubin. In *IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence*, November 1991.